# Invite Discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I am trying to read the members of a guild by invitation. As soon as we send a link from a server, information such as name, online membership and total members appears. How do I get this information? (The library in question is discord.py)

Example:

(I can't share an image, so I ask you to open the photo link:)
https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/842566116978327584/844421408019841034/unknown.png

Name: ☕|Clube do café #240|☕

Photo url: https://cdn.discordapp.com/icons/828004701148676137/62f745ee62f7fb6dd7fbc34a6b75f2df.png?size=128

Online: 112

Members: 232

Id: 806673124819992688

(I extracted this information manually, but was wondering how to do this in the code)
I have already tried to use the following message attributes: attachments, embeds, guild, stickers and system_content. Both returned empty or the invite link.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to extract that information just from the invite, you have to join the guild, also bots cannot join guilds from invites.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible with the help of the  [`fetch_invite()` function](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Client.fetch_invite)

```
invite = await client.fetch_invite(url = "https://discord.gg/Invite-ID")
```

You can then retrieve your desired [attributes](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#invite)

For example:

```
memberCount = invite.approximate_member_count
presenceCount = invite.approximate_presence_count
guildName = invite.guild.name
guildIcon = invite.guild.icon_url
guildID = invite.guild.id
```

And so on